# LMS Convergence and the Step Size ($ \mu $) Parameter

Tags: matlab, estimation, adaptive-filters, self-study, lms

I am running the LMS algorithm based on Haykin's Adaptive filter theory.
I aim to plot the cost function $\mathbf{J}$ and calculate $\mathbf{J}_{\tt min}$ and the simulation
excess mean square error $\mathbf{J}_{\tt x}$.

I have two questions:

1. Based on theory, LMS converges when $0 \lt \mu \lt \frac{2}{\lambda_{\tt max}}$.
   But this is not the
   case here since while I have calculated theoretical $\mu=0.0019$, the
   algorithm converges when $\mu$ is about $0.28$!!
2. Is this the proper way to calculate the simulation
   excess mean square error $\mathbf{J}_{\tt x}$?

Could you help me find the mistake, either in my code or in theory?

Thanks for your time guys!!

```
clear all
clc
close all

sysorder = 3;
ap1 = 1.2;
ap2 = 0.53;
h=[1; ap1; ap2];

N = 1000;
N1 = 60;

lmw2 = zeros(1,N1);
lmw3 = zeros(1,N1);
lmw4 = zeros(1,N1);

x=randn(N,1);
corr_xx=xcorr(x);
for i=0:2
for j=0:2
R_xx(i+1,j+1)= corr_xx(N+i-j);
end
end

d=conv(x,h);

[R_dd,lags]=xcorr(d,1);
corr_xd = xcorr(d,x);
for i=0:2
R_dx(i+1) = corr_xd(N+i);
end

mu_max = 2/eigs(R_xx,1);%__________________________________________________mu step
%mu_max = 2/trace(R_xx);
mu = 0.1*mu_max;
%mu = 0.28;
%__________________________________________________________________________

[Jx,lmw,lme]=lm_s(x,d,N,N1,mu);

lm_mse = lme(1,sysorder:N).^2;%____________________________________________LMS MSE
Jmin = min(lme(1,sysorder:N).^2);%_________________________________________Jmin
Jx = mean(Jx);%____________________________________________________________Jexcess

figure(1)
plot(h, 'ko');
hold on
plot(lmw(:,N1), 'r*');

figure(2)
plot([sysorder-1:N1-1],lm_mse(sysorder:N1),'-','color','r');grid on;

%__________________________________________________________________________




function [Jx,wf,e]=lm_s(x,d,N,N1,mu)%______________________________________LMS algorithm
sysorder = 3;
w = zeros ( sysorder, 1 );
wf = zeros(length(w),N);

for n = sysorder : N1 
   u = x(n:-1:n-sysorder+1);
   y(n)= w' * u;
   e(n) = d(n) - y(n);
   w = w + mu * u * e(n) ;
   wf(:,n) = w;
end 

for n =  N1+1 : N
   u = x(n:-1:n-sysorder+1) ;
   y(n) = w' * u ;
   e(n) = d(n) - y(n) ;
   Jx(n) = w'*(u*u')*w;
end 
end
```

````
LMS pseudocode:

Intitialization:
w [0] = 0

Computation:
for n = 0, 1, 2, 3, . . .
1. y[n] = wT[n]x[n].
2. e[n] = d[n] - y[n].
3. w[n + 1] = w[n] + µe[n]x[n].
end
```
````

Comment: Haykin, 4th edition (p238, Table 5.1) suggests that the upper limit is $\frac{2}{M S_{\tt max}}$ where $M$ is the filter length and $S_{\tt max}$ is the maximum value of the power spectral density of the input.  But that doesn't seem to help for your example.

Comment: i dunno if i can decode the code.  can you state the LMS equation in $\LaTeX$?  something like 

$$ y[n] = \sum\limits_{m=0}^{M} h_m[n] x[n-m] $$

$$ e[n] = y[n] - d[n] $$

$$ h_m[n+1] = h_m[n] - \mu e[n] x[n-m] $$ 

is $\mu$ that?

Comment: Robert I have included the pseudocode above.

Comment: I presume that the FIR tap coefficients are `w[n]` and it's a vector and `wT[n]` is the transpose of the vector and `wT[n]x[n]` is the dot product and `w[n + 1] = w[n] + µe[n]x[n]` is a vector equation, right?  but `e[n]` is a scaler, not a vector, right?

Comment: That's right! During the for loop, the number of elements of w[n] (tap coefficients) equal the rank of the filter's transfer function, that is 3.

Answer (score 1):

1. In that range it is guaranteed to converge. It doesn't mean it will necesseraly won't converge for higher values. If you want deeper understanding you can read about the step size in Convex Optimization context where there the step size related to the Lipschitz Constant of the function (Which matches the eigen value for Quadratic functions).
2. If you share the problem itself from the book, we'll be able to solve the problem.

Comment: What puzzles me is that it doesn't converge for the guaranteed range, but only for higher values. If you try the exact same signals using steepest descent, it does converge only in the expected range but not for higher values.

Comment: LMS is basically Stochastic Gradient Descent, nothing more or nothing less. For smaller values you probably have to make much more iterations.

Comment: Thank you Royi! But in the above example isn't there any theoretical way to determine the optimal range? It converges to zero within the first 40 iterations. Also, according to Hayes, the optimal range for steepest descent and LMS is the same.

Comment: Of course it is the same. This is what I wrote above. LMS is stochastic gradient descent. Hence all the properties of any Stochastic Gradient Descent applies to it. The range is where convergence is guaranteed, it doesn't mean ti won't converge for higher values.

Comment: In the above code this range is (0,mu_max) which is about (0,0.0019). The problem is that there is no converge there! You can try it yourself for various values

Comment: How many iterations have you tried? It could be very slow to converge. I don't understand your code. I asked you to link to the problem in the book you're trying to solve.

Comment: Sorry for the delay Royi. The book I based the code on is Haykin's _Adaptive filter theory_. The problem is to implement LMS to signals x and d, as defined on the above code (not included in the book). When I used steepest descent with μ=0.002 the cost function was minimized almost immediately. On the other hand when I used LMS with the same μ the cost function didn't converge at all, no matter the number of iterations. Can this discepancy be explained?

Comment: I can't understand the code. If you describe the problem and the generated signals model I can write my own code and test it.

Comment: _d(n)_ is the output of signal _x_ (white noise,mean 0,std 1) passed through a filter with transfer function _H(z)=1/(1+1.2*(z^-1)+0.53*(z^-2))_. I need to use LMS algorithm to approximate the filter's "unkwown" 1, 1.2 and 0.53 coefficients (system identification problem). If you try it using steepest descent it works just fine!

Comment: @k_gelloch, LMS is stochastic steepest descent.

Comment: @k_gelloch, Could you please mark my answer?